# NestJS: Unable to copy assets using nest-cli.json

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to copy a few static files under my Nest JS project but unable to see them under the dist folder.

The structure is as follows

```
src/resources/apihub-cacert.pem
src/resources/apihub-commit-msg
```

I am using the assets configuration under nest-cli.json as follows

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "deleteOutDir": true,
    "assets": [
      "resources/*"
    ]    
  }
}
```

However I do not see the files copied under the dist folder. The documentation I am following is https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo#assets and the Command used is

```
npm run start:dev (cross-env NODE_ENV=dev nest start --watch).
```

Is there anything you see amiss?

Thanks a lot,
Prabal

Answer (score 0):

I just found that I have to pass an object to the array. This works.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "deleteOutDir": true,
    "assets": [
      { "include": "resources/*", "watchAssets": true }
    ]
  }
}
```